# HTML5/CSS3 - Checkbox Image?

Tags: jquery, html, css, checkbox

I've been everywhere, but no luck.

I have to use a set of checkboxes (that will send false/true value using POST), but I want to use images instead of them.

Is it possible?

Example, trying to change checkbox background (wrong way):

http://jsfiddle.net/hpcQ4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) provides a variety of [checkbox styling options](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#checkbox). Beyond that there are a variety of [jQuery checkbox plugins](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/checkbox) that can assist you with what you are looking to do.

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need JS for this, as long as you don't mind it not working in IE8 and below (regular checkboxes will show): http://www.thecssninja.com/css/custom-inputs-using-css